# Bash script for loop not exiting when command is successful

Tags: bash

I have the following script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo ''

maxTryTimes=10

for ((i=1; i <= maxTryTimes ; i++)); do
    echo "try setup mongodb replica ${i} ..."
    mongo --port 37017 setup.js > /dev/null 2>&1 && break || sleep 1
done

if (( $i <= $maxTryTimes )); then
    echo 'mongodb replica setup success!'
    docker exec -i stock-trading-system-stock-trading-system-db-1 sh -c 'mongoimport  --port=37017 --db=stock-trading-system-db --collection=stocks --type=csv --headerline --file=//mongo-seed/MOCK_DATA.csv'
else
    echo 'mongodb replica setup failed!'
fi
```

In the for loop, the mongo command passes first time. I know this because if i add the later mongoimport command to the end of that command then it can import the data (something which is only possible if `setup.js` passes.

I got most of this script from a [github repo](https://github.com/isayme/mongo-replica-compose), and im not too familiar with bash scripts, so im asking why is this for loop not exiting? From a google search it looks like it should?

This is what `script.js` looks like:

```js
/* global rs, sleep, quit */

rs.initiate()

function tryAdd (host) {
  var status = rs.status()

  // if exist
  var isExist = status.members.find(function (member) {
    return member.name === host
  })
  if (isExist) {
    return
  }

  var res
  // try 5 times
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    res = rs.add(host)
    if (res.ok) {
      return
    }
    sleep(500)
  }

  // failed
  quit(1)
}

tryAdd('mongo1:27018')
tryAdd('mongo2:27019')
```

Comment: You are missing a dollar sign here `for ((i=1; i <= $maxTryTimes ; i++)); do`

Comment: @LMC `$` are not needed inside `((..))`

Comment: Your syntax is correct, so it must be that `mongo` is returning a failing exit status.

Comment: Is `script.js` supposed to be `setup.js`?

Comment: You can see the most recent command's exit status with `$?` but you'll have to split up your predicated command.

Comment: Try removing the `> /dev/null 2>&1` part, so you can see if the script is printing any informative messages/errors.

Comment: Are you sure `port 37017` is the correct port ?

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: Not sure why this was voted down so let me explain. If you can see that the mongo command completed and what it's status was you can quickly determine if the JS is the issue or the bash code. If you see no result output then you know the code has hung up. Hence I would suggest some simple tests like this.

Example
Insert code more simplistic like this:

```
mongo --port 37017 setup.js
result=$?
if [[ ${result} -gt 0 ]] ;then
    echo "result failed [${result}]"
    sleep 1
else
    echo "result success [${result}]"
    break
fi
```